# Recycle Bin isn't working: all the files are deleted immediately and completely

Tags: macos, finder

Well, I don't know what happening on my MTL 10.8.4, but yesterday file deleting became very strange. When I press `cmd`+`backspace` dialog window with two variants is shown: Delete and Cancel. So the Delete button removes a file completely, and bin is empty then.
[image]

So how I can fix that?

Comment: Are the files you were deleting on a network share?

Answer (score 1):

In the terminal, enter the following:

ls ~/.Trash

If you get a response "No such file or directory", then just simply restart your Mac. If not, then type this to the terminal if you're an admin:

sudo rm -ri ~/.Trash

Follow the prompts, then restart your Mac.

Source: http://www.thexlab.com/faqs/trash.html#Anchor-Empty-49575

Comment: Thx, I've seen this link, but it didn't work for me. I found another solution.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I suddenly haven't `~/.Trash` directory

```
efpies@efpies-macmini:Downloads$ ls ~/.Trash
ls: /Users/efpies/.Trash: No such file or directory
```

So I had to recreate it

```
sudo mkdir ~/.Trash
sudo chown $UID ~/.Trash
sudo chmod u+rwx ~/.Trash
```

No logouts/restarts required.

Comment: You should have been able to do this as `mkdir ~/.Trash` if that failed you have other permissions issues with ~